# If else logic in Razor DisplayFor vs TextBoxFor MVC4

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

If a certain variable is set I want a certain field to be a textbox, if it is not I want that field to simply display the value but that value is not editable.

I put some if else logic into my views and the value won't display.  Am I missing something here?

```
            @{
                if (isFlagSet) {
                    Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HostpitalFinNumber, new { @Value = Model.HostpitalFinNumber });
                    Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HostpitalFinNumber);
                }
                else {
                    Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.HostpitalFinNumber);
                }
            }
```

Update...

I changed my code to

```
            @if (isFlagSet) {
                    Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HostpitalFinNumber);
                    Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HostpitalFinNumber);
            }
            else {
                    Html.DisplayFor(m => m.HostpitalFinNumber);
            }
```

The following is the HTML being generated.  Notice how an input value is being written for Phone but not hospital fin.  Hot sure why that is happening.

```
    <tr><td>
        <label for="Phone">Phone</label>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input Value="4124880798" id="Phone" name="Phone" type="text" value="4124880798" />
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <label for="HostpitalFinNumber">HostpitalFinNumber</label>              
        </td>
        <td>

    </td></tr>
```

ANSWER

I forgot to put the @ in front of my html helper and get rid of the Semi-colons.

Comment: DisplayFor won't create an input tag by default.  Use another TextboxFor if you want an input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your Razor syntax is wrong, the correct syntax is (you don't need the surrounding `@{ }`):

```
@if (isFlagSet) {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HostpitalFinNumber)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HostpitalFinNumber)
}
else {
    @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.HostpitalFinNumber)
}
```

The Html helpers don't write directly to the response (except the one which name's start with `Render`) so you need to use the `@` to write the generated HTML into the output.

Note that you don't need to set the value by hand with expression `new { @Value = Model.HostpitalFinNumber }` because the `Html.TextBoxFor` will take care of it.

Comment: excellent eye.  I didn't even see that.  I am testing right now and as soon as my 3 minutes up, I will be posting this as an answer.  Actually I still get nothing.  Hmmm.  Something else must be a foot.  I will update my post with my findings

Comment: I forgot to add the @ to my html and get rid of the semi-colons.  Thanks.